# Deleting object that could have multiple pointers to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers

I am making a game with a lot of characters that are objects. When a character die, I want to delete all pointers too it, the problem is that I don't know how many or where these pointers are. i.e character "A", might have character "B" stored in its "field of view" array, or the character might be saved in the physics engine's "objects lying on the ground" array. Is there a way to force an object to be deleted from all arrays it exists in?

```
character.prototype._delete_self () {
    this.delete_everywhere();
}
```

I have tried to run trough all arrays the character might be in, but that took a whole lot of performance. I also bumped into the problem where if I ran trough an array using the value `i`, the "for loop" easily got out of sync since it got shorter. Is it possible to first delete a position in an array, and then later compress the array later on?

```
var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
arr[3]=null;
document.write("1: "+arr);
arr.compress();
document.write("2: "+arr);
```

The document:

```
1: 1,2,,4,5
2: 1,2,4,5
```

Comment: If your only problem is with mutating an array within a loop, simply iterate over it in **reverse order**.

Comment: In reversed order, why didn't I think of that... Thank you

Comment: For the general problem, it seems like you'd want a *weak* reference to the object. Only `WeakMap`s provide this functionality, but I don't know how well this could be applied here (and it's still experimental): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap